# How to override a site's jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet, userscripts

Specifically the **delayedAutoNext** function on the homepage of pitchfork.com that rotates the pitchfork.tv images — I want to change the setTimeout value to a different number.

How can I do this with a bookmarklet and/or a userscript?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably have to wrap the page in your own code, though, let's be honest, that's hacking a site.

Comment: Fair enough, I will assume that you like every website's functionality and don't use any add-ons or extensions for your browser to manipulate webpages.

Comment: Those are different issues. To get what you want, you need to change the way the site works, not just the way it looks or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's in the scope of an anonymous closure you cannot access it directly, what you would need to do is remove the click event handlers on the links/prev/next and write new handlers for them.

So basically you would rewrite the entire anonymous function in `$(document).ready()` add in

```
links.unbind('click');
next.unbind('click');
prev.unbind('click');
```

After the variable declarations, and then adjust the milliseconds on the setTimeout of 'delayedAutoNext()' function.

Comment: Can't get it working, do I need to use **unsafeWindow** as well?